# how to use django signals using singnals.py

Tags: django

the django signal is not working when am using signals.py but it works if i use the normal models.py

**accounts/signals.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import Profile


def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
       print("profile created")

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


def update_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created == False:
       instance.profile.save()
       print('profile updated')

post_save.connect(update_profile, sender=User)
```

**accounts/app.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'accounts'

     def ready(self):
         import accounts.signals
```

**accounts/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
]
```

Comment: What to you mean by the django signal is not working when am using signals.py but it works if i use the normal models.py ?

Comment: you can use signals either bu creating a separate python file named signals.py or you can decide not to use a separate file and just type the code in models.py

Comment: if i copy exact code to my models.py, it works but if i try using the code with a separate file signals.py it does not work

Comment: why are you saving instance.profile.save() in  update_profile receiver ? Is OneToOne relationship exist between user and profile ?

Comment: yes, OneToOne relationship exist between user and profile

Answer (score 0):

signals.py

Use only one receiver for User and Profile not multiple.

```
from django.dispatch import Signal, receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: #user created
       Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
       print("user and profile created")
    else: #user updated
        print('user updated')

@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile)
def profile_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if  created: # profile created
        pass 
    else: # profile updated 
       print("profile updated")
```

When you create new User, profile also created with User in signals receiver , but when you update user only user updated not profile or when you update Profile, only profile updated not user that's why signals not working in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**this worked for me**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    print("profile created")


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
    instance.profile.save()
    print('profile updated')
```